# Second Text for Multivariable Calculus

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I took a rather disappointing multivariable calculus course this semester -- the (visiting) professor was not demanding at all. We didn't get to what is in most standard calculus III curriculum. What we did was at a nearly trivial level. I plan to take real analysis next year and don't want to be at a disadvantage in future courses so I would like to go through a  multivariable text this summer.

What is a good multivariable calculus **textbook** with the following properties,

- is cheap or free
- has plenty of problems
- isn't an analysis text (but is above the level of stewart)

Comment: I just purchased "Advanced Calculus of Several Variables" by C.H. Edwards Jr. and like it so far. Some exposure to linear algebra may be helpful though.

Comment: @AdamEury I am familiar with linear algebra. Excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Not a textbook, but have you seen the Multivariable Calculus course offered on [MIT Open Courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/index.htm)? I haven't used it myself, put it looks like a pretty standard course. There are lecture notes, recorded lectures, and problem sets. If you'd rather use a textbook, you can see what book(s) are recommended there.